# How to correctly refer to an object of a class from a different class in C++?

Tags: c++, sfml

I am using C++ and SFML to make a top-down Zombie shooter. For now I have a player I can move around who can shoot but I am trying to have a basic AI for a Zombie who chases the player based on player position.

For some reason the zombie is moving in a straight direction rather than chasing player. I believe that the problem has to do with incorrect player position being used to calculate the direction of the zombie. I am constantly getting 0 for position of player when using the position value from player class in the zombie class.

But I can't seem to figure out how to fix the problem. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my code so far:

**Player.cpp**

```
//GetPosition() is getting player position
//I even tried getting output of player's x and y position in this class and 
//its correctly showing player's position
sf::Vector2f Player::GetPosition()
{
  xPos = playerSprite.getPosition().x;
  yPos = playerSprite.getPosition().y;

  sf::Vector2f position = sf::Vector2f(xPos, yPos);

  //Correctly outputs position
  std::cout << "X: " << position.x << " Y: " << position.y << std::endl;

  return position;
}
```

**Zombie.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Player.h"
class Zombie
{
public:
  Zombie();

  //Here I am trying to create a player object to access player position 
  //variable to use for Zombie direction calculations
  Player p1;
  Player *player = &p1;

  sf::Texture zombieTexture;
  sf::Sprite zombieSprite;

  sf::Vector2f zombiePosition;
  sf::Vector2f playerPosition;
  sf::Vector2f direction;
  sf::Vector2f normalizedDir;

  int xPos;
  int yPos;
  float speed;
  void Move();

};
```

**Zombie.cpp**

```
void Zombie::Move()
{

// Make movement
xPos = zombieSprite.getPosition().x;
yPos = zombieSprite.getPosition().y;

zombiePosition = sf::Vector2f(xPos, yPos);

playerPosition = player->GetPosition();

//Incorrectly outputs player position
//This outputs 0 constantly. But why?
std::cout << "X: " << playerPosition.x << " Y: " << 
playerPosition.y << std::endl;

direction = playerPosition - zombiePosition;
normalizedDir = direction / sqrt(pow(direction.x, 2) + pow(direction.y, 2));

speed = 2;

//Rotate the Zombie relative to player position
const float PI = 3.14159265;

float dx = zombiePosition.x - playerPosition.x;
float dy = zombiePosition.y - playerPosition.y;

float rotation = (atan2(dy, dx)) * 180 / PI;
zombieSprite.setRotation(rotation + 45);

sf::Vector2f currentSpeed = normalizedDir * speed;

zombieSprite.move(currentSpeed);
}
```

Comment: Note that without SFML (which I personally don't have), we can't run any of this. Is all of this code necessary to reproduce your problem? Can you peel code away while still reproducing until you get a small(er) self-contained example that we can run ourselves to see your issue?

Comment: I'm confused. The code in `Zombie::Move()` assigns a value to member variable `playerPosition` but then prints the value of `player.playerPosition` and comments that that's wrong. Why not print the value you just got?

Comment: The mysterious object called "playerSprite" does not appear to be defined anywhere in the shown code. As such, the shown code appears to fail to meet the requirements for a [mcve] as explained in stackoverflow.com [help], making this question un-answerable. Furthermore, if the problem is stated as "How to correctly refer to an object of a class from a different class in C++", then the only code that needs to be shown is a declaration of two classes, called "A" and "B", together with a few lines of code that define the situation where "correctly referring" is an issue, in some way.

Comment: @scohe001 You make a valid point. I will narrow down the code which is necessary for the problem.

Comment: @TimRandall That is a typo actually. I added the print last minute before posting. Fixing that does not solve the issue, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does the zombie know which player to chase? In your `Zombie` class you have a member `p1` which is never moved and `player` always points to that. Probably what you need is a function

```
void Zombie::chasePlayer(Player* p)
{
   player = p;
}
```

and then in main.cpp add a line

```
zombie.chasePlayer(&player);
```

More generally you might like to e.g. check which is the closest player and chase that one instead.